# How do you display buttons in the Outlook Quick Access Toolbar using XML

Tags: c#, xml, vsto, outlook-addin

I've created a new Outlook 2013 addin C# VSTO project in VS 2012. I've added an XML file to customise the ribbon to add a new tab with 2 existing buttons. But I can't make buttons appear in the Quick Access Toolbar (QAT).

Below is the XML I've written. It displays the new Tab and buttons. But doesn't display the specified buttons in the Quick Access Toolbar.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="Ribbon_Load">
    <ribbon>
        <qat>
            <sharedControls>
                <button idMso="NewMailMessage" visible="true" />
                <button idMso="NewTask" visible="true" />
            </sharedControls>
        </qat>
    <tabs>
        <tab id="newTab" label="New Tab" insertBeforeMso="TabCalendarTableView">
            <group id="newGroup" label="New">
                <button idMso="NewMailMessage" size="large"/>
                <button idMso="NewAppointment" size="large"/>
                <button idMso="NewContact" size="large"/>
                <button idMso="NewDistributionList" size="large"/>
                <button idMso="NewTask" size="large"/>
                <button idMso="MailNewItemMenu" size="large"/>
            </group>
         </tab>
    </tabs>
</ribbon>
```

What do I need to change to make it display the buttons in the Quick Access Toolbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the **startFromScratch** attribute to the ribbon attribute.

Take a look at the following series of articles in MSDN:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338199(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa722523(v=office.12).aspx)

They contain the following text:

> The Quick Access Toolbar. Can be authored only in start from scratch mode.
>
> You can customize the Quick Access Toolbar by setting the startFromScratch attribute of the Ribbon element to true.